# Identifier not found when calling a function under a function

Tags: c++, clock, identifier

I trying to develop a program that displays a 12 hour and 24 hour clock at the same time. But whenever I compile, I get a build error saying 'GetAM_PM': identifier not found. I get this error on line 26 in spite of using the same variable from my function parameter. What could be the root of this problem? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

//converting it into 12 hour format
int TwelveHourFormat(int twelve_hours) {
return (twelve_hours == 0 || twelve_hours == 12) ? 12 : 
twelve_hours % 12;
}


//printing the 12 hour format
void Display_12_HourFormat(int seconds, int minutes, int 
twelve_hours) {

cout.fill('0');
cout << TwelveHourFormat(twelve_hours) << ":" << minutes << ":" 
<< seconds << " " << GetAM_PM(twelve_hours);
}

//printing the 24 hour format
void Display_24_HourFormat(int seconds, int minutes, int 
twenty_four_hours) {
cout.fill('0');
cout << twenty_four_hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;
}
    
void AddHour(int hour) {

hour = (hour + 1) % 24;

}
    
void AddMinute(int hour, int min) {
if (min == 59) {
    AddHour(hour);
}
min = (min + 1) % 60;
}

void AddSecond(int min, int sec) {

if (sec == 59) {
    AddMinute(min, sec);
}
sec = (sec + 1) % 60;
}

// function return AM/PM respect to hour of time
string GetAM_PM(int twelve_hours) {

return twelve_hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
}


// This method prints the menu options
void DisplayMenu() {
cout << "Chada Tech Clocks Menu" << endl;
cout << "[1] Add one hour" << endl;
cout << "[2] Add one minute" << endl;
cout << "[3] Add one second" << endl;
cout << "[4] Exit program" << endl;

}

 int main()
{  
int seconds, minutes, hours;

//obtains current time in seconds
time_t total_seconds = time(0); 

//getting values of seconds, minutes and hours
struct tm ct;
localtime_s(&ct, &total_seconds);

seconds = ct.tm_sec;
minutes = ct.tm_min;
hours = ct.tm_hour;

    // Variable declared
    int option;
    do
    {
    // DisplayMenu function is called
    DisplayMenu();
    
    cin >> option;
    // If user input is 1, Clock function is called
    if (option == 1) {

        TwelveHourFormat(hours);
        AddHour(hours);
        GetAM_PM(hours);
        Display_12_HourFormat(seconds, minutes, hours);
        Display_24_HourFormat(seconds, minutes, hours);
        
    }
    // If the option is 2, the Clock function is called
    else if (option == 2) {

        AddMinute(minutes, seconds);
        GetAM_PM(hours);

    }
    // If the option is 3, the Clock function is called
    else if (option == 3) {

        AddSecond(minutes, seconds);
        GetAM_PM(hours);
        
    }
    // If the option is 4, exit message prints and application 
    stops running
    else if (option == 4) {

        cout << "You have exited the application.";
        break;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have entered an invalid input." << endl;
    }
} while (option != 4);
}
```

Comment: Where is GetAM_PM defined or declared in relation to main? Above it, below it, in a separate file?

Comment: In the file that I copied from, GetAM_PM is defined above the Main function

Comment: `DisplayMenu`, `Display_24_HourFormat`, `AddMinute` and `AddSecond` aren't declared or defined. What functions do you expect it to call? Please show a [mre], similar to [this](https://godbolt.org/z/T8c5Whjr7) - but with those functions declared and defined.

Comment: please show the complete file and the actual error messages

Comment: on what line are you getting this error? I can see GetAM_PM being called in multiple places, for example if Display_12_HourFormat is defined *before* GetAM_PM you would get the error there (but not in main since you mentioned GetAM_PM was defined before it). 

It really should be one block of code instead of multiple because for this kind of error order matters (assuming its not a simple typo issue)

Comment: I just pasted the complete file. And I've added that my build error occurs at line 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move these lines to the beginning, before any other function:

```
// function return AM/PM respect to hour of time
string GetAM_PM(int twelve_hours) {

return twelve_hours >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
}
```

It is not this case, but if you end up with circular dependency, try to declare the methods in a .h or forward declare the methods in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `GetAM_PM` before you define `Display_12_HourFormat`. Otherwise it'll not be known by the compiler at the time it parses the `Display_12_HourFormat` function in which `GetAM_PM` is called.

Comment: yeah i was thinking that OP means the whole function GetAM_PM is above main since defining and declaring are not really the same thing.

Comment: i thought that in C++ implicit declarations are not allowed.

Comment: wow thanks i never knew !